# Django Models : array of fields

Tags: django

I need a form with 'hundreds' of integer input fields.
I was thinking to create an array of integer fields in my model, but this doesn't seem to function:

```
class Array(models.Model):
   name=models.CharField(max_length=10)
   data=[]
   for i in range(100):
       data.append(models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True))
```

Via de shell I can create a record, change a data field and store...

```
from app1.models import Array    
a=Array(name='first')
a.data[0]=10
a.save()
```

but retrieving later doesn't function: I get only <django.db.models.fields.IntegerField> but no actual values...

I know about the ArrayField in postgres, but I just use SQLite...
Any smarter way than creating 100 individual IntegerFields?

Comment: Why not create `ForeignKey` to other model that has field as `IntegerField`

Comment: This is not solving the issue. The issue is having a mechanism to create 100 IntegerField s easily. I used an alternative of CharacterField with 'integers separated with commas' validation + translating in a template that CharacterField via a {% FOR loop into integer input fields. However I don't like the solution...